# PhpMyAdmin Query for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, mysql

How do I query PhpMyAdmin to delete WordPress comments where the commenter added their website?

That is, comments by people who used a url: Name, Email, **Website**.

I want to delete comments that have **Website** data.

Comment: please show us what you have got already

Comment: See this page for background: http://www.blogopreneur.com/2009/04/08/mass-delete-pending-comments-from-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

try the folloing query, but before put it in action, back up your database first.

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments
WHERE comment_author_url like '%http://%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_comments` table has the fields `comment_author`, `comment_author_email`, `comment_author_url`, and `comment_content`, among others.

Note that before performing any database manipulation you should [back up your database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database#Backup_Process_with_phpMyAdmin), since these commands if used improperly will delete *all comments* from your blog.

If you want to remove any comment where the author placed a website in the comment_author_url field (which many do to identify their "home" blog,) you can do this:

```
delete from wp_comments where comment_author_url like '%http://%';
```

If instead you want to remove a comment where the author placed a website in the *content* of the comment (as is common with comment spam) you can do

```
delete from wp_comments where comment_content like '%http://%';
```

Edit your question to have more specifics about what you want to do if this does not answer your question.